# Failed wireless connection on a Thinkpad edge E520 with a Centrino Wireless-N 1000

Tags: 11.10, wireless, intel-wireless

I can use my wireless connection without problems either on ubuntu 10.04 or win7, but can't on ubuntu 11.10. 
I'm just unable to find any connection.
On terminal

```
rfkill list all
```

with only wireless softblocked;
when trying to

```
rfkill unblock all
```

or
`rfkill unblock wifi`

it is still softblocked.

```
nm-tool
```

Shows, that i'm disconected and state for wlan0 is unavaible

```
lshw -C network
*-network 
   description: Wireless interface 
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 
   vendor: Intel Corporation 
   physical id: 0 
   bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0 
   logical name: wlan0 
   version: 00 
   serial: 74:e5:0b:18:20:a0 
   width: 64 bits 
   clock: 33MHz 
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless 
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn 
   resources: irq:45 memory:e1d00000-e1d01fff
```

So is physical id=0 a problem? is that ubuntu dosen't recognize my wireless interface?

Is there anything to change this? Or just use the older version of ubuntu?

Comment: please add the entire output of `rfkill list all` into your question.

Comment: I don't think the physical id is the problem -- my non-working centrino wireless network card and my perfectly working realtek ethernet cart both show physical id: 0.

Answer (score 1):

answer from here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1760181

```
$ rfkill list all
$ sudo rmmod -f acer_wmi
$ sudo rfkill unblock all
$ sudo su
# echo "blacklist acer_wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
# exit
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the above problem while trying out different distributions and going to the different discussion forums.

"To (temporarily) get the wireless working on newer kernels:

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode.backup
sudo modprobe -r iwlagn
sudo modprobe iwlagn
```

This should make the wireless use the old 1000-3.ucode which works at the moment."